# Tem como configurar um pull automático usando agendador de tarefas do windows?

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando encontrar uma maneira de atualizar um sistema local em um servidor utilizando versionamento git para ter melhor segurança e controle no meu projeto, mas ainda sou bem leigo no assunto. Acontece que eu queria encontrar uma maneira de sincronizar a máquina local, o github e o servidor de uma forma mais automática, considerando que o servidor não está na mesma rede local a solução que pensei foi criar um repositório remoto para o projeto e configurar um script no agendador de tarefas do servidor para fazer o pull em um dia e horário específico. Daí surgem algumas perguntas:

Como eu crio um script para rodar comandos no git?
Existe outra forma melhor de fazer isso? E se fossem vários outros servidores que eu tivesse que atualizar?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso, e é através de uma prática conhecida como Continuous Delivery!

A prática de entrega contínua, em português, ou simplesmente CD, é responsável por executar o deploy nos ambientes necessários realizando assim a entrega da aplicação. Normalmente existem ambientes de desenvolvimento (DEV), homologação (HMG) ou produção (PRD), ou apenas DEV e PRD, ou somente PRD mas com uso de slots, comum no Azure quando se utiliza WebApp,... Ou no caso de aplicação mobile o seu último ambiente pode ser a própria loja onde irá disponibilizar o app para os usuários. Qualquer que seja a quantidade e o propósito dos seus ambientes você precisa de uma orquestração entre eles para fazer esse deploy, ou instalação.

Quando se está desenvolvendo, você irá querer que qualquer commit no repositório seja instalado no ambiente de DEV. Já em homologação apenas quando tiver alguma feature pronta, funcional. E em produção somente quando o cliente aprovar ou estiver homologado. Para que esse processo funcione é preciso orquestrar o deploy entre esses ambientes. Várias ferramentas podem fazer isso, inclusive algumas também a etapa de integração de código, onde é feita compilação ou transpilação, os testes de unidade são executados, e o que mais for necessário para gerar um artefato instalável.

Sugestões:

1. [Azure DevOps](https://dev.azure.com), funciona não só com Azure, mas aws e com infra local
2. [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), mais recente, mas se o seu código já está no Github, pode ser uma boa alternativa
3. [Relacionar o item](https://www.jenkins.io/), você deverá instalar ou rodar a partir de um container, pode até rodar ele em alguma nuvem